# Permission patterns in android application

Tags: android, android-permissions

This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6uKsIsIwxFcOUZtb3AyRGxvSW8/view?usp=sharing) to the research paper Android Malware Detection with Contrasting Permission Patterns.

1. What are permission pattern as mentioned in this research paper?
2. Can there be more than one permission patterns in one android
   application? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

In the paper, they mention this:

> In our prior research [8], we have brought out a method for
>   contrasting permission pattern mining.

If you check on the end of the paper what the 8th reference is, it is:

> [8] MOONSAMY V, RONG J, LIU S, et al. Contrasting Permission Patterns
>   between Clean and Malicious Android Applications[M]//ZIA T., A.
>   ZOMAYA, V. VARADHARAJAN, and M. MAO. Security and Privacy in
>   Communication Networks.  Springer International Publishing, 2013:
>   69-85.

I could find an appropiate version for you on [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=l4O6BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=Contrasting%20Permission%20Patterns%20between%20Clean%20and%20Malicious%20Android%20Applications&source=bl&ots=0X4UzL4wyb&sig=AQTapRNo9pDxxxnbwfWetXFbLd8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBWoVChMIgpSD2p_syAIVhloUCh0Pjgyk#v=onepage&q=Contrasting%20Permission%20Patterns%20between%20Clean%20and%20Malicious%20Android%20Applications&f=false)
I'm not sure if I'm legally allowed to copy the result here, so check yourself on the top of page 76 and 79.

The base idea was that they gathered a lot of clean and malicious applications, and checked their permissions. Then they looked for the frequency of each permission. Then they observed that bad applications use the `CALL_PHONE` permission a lot more than clean ones (obviously), so they can set up a pattern, like this one (this is just an example):

If the app requests the `CALL_PHONE` and `READ_SMS` permissions, than it is 134% more likely to be malicious.

So to answer your second question: A permission pattern is the set of permissions an app requests. Then they check this against their pattern recognition, and turn this into a value, which describes how malicious it could be. But this is not an answer like it is malicious or not, it is just some kind of probability.

The Hangouts app for example might require `CALL_PHONE` and `SEND_SMS` permissions, but it does not use this against the will of the user (hopefully :)), so it is not malicious.

Comment: do you have any android malware and clean dataset?

Comment: No, I don't have any.